# Support all screen sizes and android versions

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm developing an Android application and **I want to use images as backgrounds for the activities. I'm targeting from API 8 to the latest. I would like to know what is the best way to do this.**

I've read [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

So, I made 4 images for each background with this dimensions: 320x480, 480x800, 600x1024, 800x1280. First, I put the files in this folders respectively: `drawable-sw320dp, drawable-sw480dp, drawable-sw600dp, drawable-sw720dp`. Then, I realized that this only works for Android 3.2 and above, so I needed to add the small, normal, large and xlarge folders. In order not to duplicate files, I followed the ideas of [this section of the first article](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).

The final structure is:

- All images inside the `drawable` folder, with different names for each dimension
- An xml file in each of this folders: `values-sw320dp, values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge`

For example, for the background of the main activity I have:

- `drawable\bg_main_320.png`
- `drawable\bg_main_480.png`
- `drawable\bg_main_600.png`
- `drawable\bg_main_720.png`
- And `drawables.xml` in the eight folders named above.

The content of `drawables.xml` for the `values-sw480dp` and `values-normal` folders is:

```
<resources>
    <item name="bg_main" type="drawable">@drawable/bg_main_480</item> 
</resources>
```

I tested this in Android 2.3.7 and 4.0.3 and it is working fine. However, I'm getting this Lint warning for every image: "Found bitmap drawable res/drawable/bg_main_480.png in densityless folder. Issue: Ensures that images are not defined in the density-independent drawable folder". I know what it means, but I will not continue creating more images for each dp since it is pointless.

Is the structure I'm using right? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 17):

`/res/drawable` should not have any image files, it should only include drawables defined using XML. You should place your actual image files in qualified drawable directories based on the target pixel-density. If you don't want to specify any qualifier, place them in 
`/res/drawable-nodpi`

Comment: The Lint help says: "If the icon really is density independent (for example a solid color) you can place it in drawable-nodpi.". So, I wasn't sure if using that folder was right. Anyway, is the structure I used the right one? (dimensions and folders)

Comment: It seems like it would work, but you would have to test this with a variety of device form factors. Do you absolutely need to use images this way? If there's any way to use a nine-patch image or a tiled image, either could make life easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For now, I will move the images to /res/drawable-nodpi. Maybe, in the future I will think some way to recreate the images with more complex drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You can find valuable information here [info](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

and also in "res" forlder you can see different drawables:
36x36 for low-density

48x48 for medium-density

72x72 for high-density

96x96 for extra high-density

you can put your files for particular resolution.

Comment: Did you read the post? I already mentioned that article and the question is not about the dp folders.